Apache 2.4 config for fcgi with custom socket listening web app
I need a config for apache 2.4 which just connects to an open socket and talks fcgi over it.
I am writing my own fcgi-enabled web app. By now, it opens a listening socket and when a web server (nginx at the moment) connects to it (when getting a request from a browser) they talk fcgi over that socket. (So my app basically implements a fcgi responder role acc. to fcgi protocol spec and serves some basic pages over it.)
My goal is to enable apache 2.4 to replace nginx in this scenario.
I'd like to start basic:

http listening port is 2000 for now so no root or priv drop needed
lauch httpd as normal user with cusomized config file (-f parameter)
httpd does not need to launch my app, it should expect an open port stated in its conf
ssl (encryption/security) irrelevant right now (topic for a later date)
simple apache conf for serving static pages works already

This my simplistic httpd.conf. It works for serving static pages.
DocumentRoot "/tmp/nginx/pages"
Listen 2000
PidFile "/tmp/nginx/httpd.pid"
ErrorLog "/tmp/nginx/error_log"
ServerRoot "/usr/lib64/apache2"
LoadModule authz_core_module mod_authz_core.so

# LoadModule proxy_module mod_proxy.so
# LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module mod_proxy_fcgi.so
# ProxyPass /a unix://tmp/nginx/socket_fcgiMain.s
# LoadModule fcgid_module /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_fcgid.so
# FcgidIPCDir "/tmp/nginx"

My questions:
which is the correct fcgi module for apache:

mod_proxy_fcgi.so
mod_fcgid.so
something else?

How to configure it?

nowadays you should be using mod_proxy_fcgi, check mod_proxy_fcgi documentation. To use it the easier method for me is the handler method, mentioned in the linked page.

@DanielFerradal thanks for that hint. Can you give some more?
This is my httpd.conf
DocumentRoot "/tmp/nginx/pages" 

Listen 2000

PidFile "/tmp/nginx/httpd.pid"
ErrorLog "/tmp/nginx/error_log"
ServerName localhost
LoadModule proxy_module mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module mod_proxy_fcgi.so
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
ProxyPass "/myapp/" "fcgi://localhost:9000/"

My app has a listening socket on localhost:9000 however httpd does not even try to talk to it. What am I missing?

ProxyRequests on should be off, that is for forward proxying, what kind of requests do you make? with that config anything like /myapp/.* should be proxied.

I have written my own app which opens a unix socket and expects a web server to talk to it using the fcgi protocol via that socket.
I have such a working solution already with nginx as web server (accepting requests from clients and forwarding them using fcgi to my app). Now, I'd like to replace nginx with apache 2.4.
